# JavaScript String Limit?

Tags: javascript

I have a question concerning my javascript code (Sorry my english is not that good). The code works, however, with only one data entry, the string in the HTML which results, gets cut off near the end (last few characters seems to be dropped, the length of the character drop is consistent). I'm wondering if I'm hitting a string limit or something similar. The problem data entry (which gets stored in the var gDef below) is 4110 characters long which doesn't seem like it should be a problem... Help?

The following is my code:

```
gI = document.gForm.gLinks.options[document.gForm.gLinks.selectedIndex].value;

definition = "";        

gWord = (g[gI].getElementsByTagName("NAME")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);

gDef = (g[gI].getElementsByTagName("DEFINITION")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue).replace(/\n/g,'<br />').replace(/\[/g,'<').replace(/\]/g,'>');

definition += ("<div class=\"word\">");
definition += ("<h3>"+gWord+"</h3>");
definition += ("<div class=\"definition\">"+gDef+"</div>");
definition += ("</div>");

document.getElementById("showGlossary").innerHTML = definition;
```

Comment: If you try: `console.log(gDef);`  Does the full string appear in the console?

Comment: What does class "definition" look like?

Comment: Class "definition" looks like this:
.definition
    { 
    background: #FF9;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 5px;
    }

Comment: cool, I didn't know about console.log. It does look like at this line: gDef = (g[gI].getElementsByTagName("DEFINITION")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue).replace(/\n/g,'<br />').replace(/\[/g,'<').replace(/\]/g,'>'); 

the code is cutting the string

Comment: hmm... after playing with the console a bit more... if I delete all the .replace() in the above line to get (g[gI].getElementsByTagName("DEFINITION")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue).replace(/\‌​n/g,'<br />'); the console shows that all the characters are there. If I load the page in IE8 its fine. If I load the page in FireFox 9.0.1, the string is cut as before. Maybe this is a bug in FireFox?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the browser isn't hiding the string partially?  The CSS property `text-overflow` can cause this.